# FIR low-pass filter is designed with Kaiser window, but the frequency response results all NaN

Tags: matlab, filter, signal-processing

A problem, using Kaiser window to design FIR low-pass filter in Matlab without using `filterDesigner`.The requirements for boundary frequency, stopband starting frequency, passband tolerance and maximum stopband gain are as follows: ωp =0.4 π, ws=0.6 π, δ1= 0.01 and δ2= 0.001.The problem is the result vectors of the frequency response `H`are all NaN.
I have checked the formula it seems ok.Most likely `freqz` but i don't know what went wrong.

```
% calculate N
delta1 = 0.01;
delta2 = 0.001;
A = -20 * log10(delta1);
delta_w = 0.2;
N = (A - 8) / (2.285 * delta_w);
N=floor(N);
% calculate beta
beta = 0.1102 * (A - 8.7);

% window 
w = zeros(1, N);
for n = 1:N
    w(n) = besseli(0, beta * sqrt(1 - (2 * n / N - 1)^2)) / besseli(0, beta);
end

% calculate h(n)
h = zeros(1, N);
omega_p = 0.4;
for n = 1:N
    h(n) = (sin(omega_p * (n - N / 2)) / (pi * (n - N / 2))) * w(n);
end

% frequency response
[H, w] = freqz(h, 1, 512);

%  draw amplitude response
figure;
plot(w / pi, 20 * log10(abs(H)));
xlabel('Normalized Frequency (\times\pi rad/sample)');
ylabel('Magnitude (dB)');

% draw phase response
figure;
plot(w / pi, angle(H));
xlabel('Normalized Frequency (\times\pi rad/sample)');
ylabel('Phase (rad)');

% display N
disp(['Filter order: ' num2str(N)]);
```

Any suggestion would be helpful

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Have you check your coefficients `h`? When plotting them you see that there is a gap in the middle. The coefficient with the index 35 is NaN.

Comment: God I see it. Indeed `h` index 35 is NaN. And why it cause a `NaN`?@Irreducible

Comment: @ShepardMerose Because for `n=35` you are dividing `0` by `0`.  You need to include a special case for that value in the line `h(n) = ···`

Comment: Alright I guess part of my calculation must go wrong, I would check it carefully once more. Dividing 0 by 0 shouldn't occur.@LuisMendo

Comment: In general debugging your own code before asking a question should be the first thing to do, also see: [how-to-debug-small-programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)